# When I open wifi and connected, TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() and TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() always return 0

Tags: java, android

When I open wifi and connected, `TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()` and `TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()` always return 0, but close wifi, get the value is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to doc.

`getMobileRxBytes` return number of bytes received across mobile networks since device boot. Counts packets across all mobile network interfaces, and always increases monotonically since device boot.

And `getMobileTxBytes` return number of bytes transmitted across mobile networks since device boot. Counts packets across all mobile network interfaces, and always increases monotonically since device boot.

But it works according to doc only in `Android 2 - 4`. In `Android 5 - 6 or even 7` it return zero when reconnect your mobile data.

There is an issue for the same.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37009612